# how to store connection string in dll / class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I want to store a connection string in my dll. I created a class library to store connection string. How to pass this connection string value to `web.config` file? Or how to get this value in another project?

```
public class Class1
{
    public string encrypt()
    {
        string connection = @"Server=SYSTEM-6\SQLEXPRESS;Database=devleadsdb;Integrated Security=True;";
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instantiate an object of that type and call the method: `Class1 myClass1 = new Class1(); string connStr = myClass1.encrypt();` The name of the method is really bad - the name of the method should describe what it does - and here, there's absolutely no trace of any encryption going on - so why is it called `encrypt()`?? It should be called `GetConnectionString()` or something like that - do tell what it **really** does ....

Comment: im storing connction string in dll. so that im doing like that. if any good way please advice me.. u r right that name should be getconnectionstring@marc_s

Comment: The problem with storing it inside a DLL like this : it's **hard-coded** now - if you want to change even just the name of the server it's running on, you **must** update your DLL and re-deploy your application - just to change the connection string. Not a very good idea generally - I would just put it into a **config** file - that's much easier to deal with, much easier to change (e.g. from dev to testing to production)

Comment: im doing this because of security reasons, so that any other person cant read creadetials. because web.config file is visible to all@marc_s

Comment: You can [**encrypt** the `web.config`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - and `web.config` is **only** visible to those who have direct access to the **web server** - which should be severely restricted anyways.... and also: your DLL can be **easily** decompiled back into C# code and then it would show the connection string in plain text again - this is **NOT** a safe security measure!

Comment: Agreed with that @marc_s says. You're going to cause yourself a lot of unnecessary hassle if your application is not flexible. If it's coded within the dll, you'll need to redeploy that dll again. If you're concerned about security, just encrypt the web.config file.

Comment: im unable to encrypt file , i have encrypted for web.config but it didnt worked in windows app. because it is app.config. can u send me any link by which we can encrypt app.config file@jelly

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class library to embed an encryption and decryption algorithm. Then use that class to read and write encrypted connection string to connectionStrings xml section on web/app.config. Refer this library to your main project.